# writing COUNTIFS in python based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, excel, pandas, function, numpy

I have an issue which I have been able to solve on excel but need to also be able to solve this in python.
I have a table of customers with members who have terminated their membership and their purchase history. I want to be able to count number of purchases each customer has before and after their membership termination.

for the first row I used the countifs formulae =COUNTIFS(C:C,">"&B2,A:A,A2) to calculate the number of purchases the customer has done since termination.

is there a way to do this in python? I have tried using groupby but it doesnt really output the same data
[here is the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkAUY.png)

Comment: Please copy/paste as plain text few lines of your worksheet to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Group by is the technique you need, may be you're doing it wrong.
Try the following for counting purchases made after termination.

```sql
select id, count(*) from table where term < purchase group by id;
```

Replace `term` and `purchase` with the column names, and `<` with `>` if you want to count the purchases done before the termination.

The pandas query for the corresponding SQL statement is

```py
df[df['Membership Termination date'] < df['Purchase date']].groupby('ID').size()
```

Comment: this looks more like SQL than pandas

Comment: @sammywemmy I've added the pandas query for the given SQL statement.